# Java reflection getting array class of a given class

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

So I have this Class c, and I want to get the Class object that represents an array of the type c represents. Is it possible? I can't find any way...

Clarifying: somewhere else I have:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("data.Person");
```

OK, so I have this class `c` now. And I want to have the `Class` that represents the array of persons. The same as if I did:

```
Class<?> cs = data.Person[].class;
```

But I want to do it with reflection. I know nothing about the original class, but the reference `c` to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want `Array.newInstance(c, 0).getClass()`.

Answer (score 2):

To create Class instance of some array type you can also use Class.forName(). You just need to surround base type with `[L` and `;` (numbers of `[` is number of dimensions), so

- class of one dimensional array of Strings `String[].class` would be `[Ljava.lang.String;`,
- class of two dimensional array of Strings `String[][].class` would be `[[Ljava.lang.String;`.
- and in your case data.Person[].class would be `[Ldata.Person;`

This means that all you need to do is

- add `[L` and `;` if type is not array,
- add another `[` at start if type is already array.

So for dynamic `c` you can use something like

```
Class.forName(c.isArray()?"["+c.getName():"[L"+c.getName()+";")
```